# Does uniform subsampling of a biased sample reduce the bias?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design

In a paper I am reading now I found the following statement:

> Then, of 200 candidates for the study, 50 were at random selected using a computer-generated randomization list (MS Excel). This way, even if a certain “selection bias” would have been present, at least this bias would be “diluted” 1–4 by the random selection procedure.

I don't see how this method helps to reduce the bias, because I assume that the sampled candidates would have the same distribution as the original candidates.

How does it work and is this practice used often?

Comment: I agree with your assessment, I cannot see how this could possibly alter the bias.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. For example, if we have a 2-fold bias for women developing hyperthyroidism and 200 sequential hyperthyroid cases in a particular clinic accepting all patients sent, looking at 50 randomized or sequential cases would not change the underlying bias. Moreover, if we introduced a collection bias by only examining the first 100 males, which would take longer, and the first 100 females to introduce a bias that balances the sexes, we would not change that selection bias by randomly sub-selecting only 50 cases. We would make the selection bias less statistically obvious for the smaller case numbers, but the bias itself would be unchanged. In the extreme, if we randomly choose only one patient, the sex will be either but not both, so our certainty of sex selection bias, i.e., via its significance testing, is extremely low.